# Unlocked bootloader, not booting

Tags: nexus-5x

I unlocked the bootloader on my Nexus 5X phone. When I tried to boot into recovery mode, I get the standard message that my device isn't being scanned for corruption. I expected it... but then nothing. It doesn't boot, it doesn't change. I tried relocking the bootloader in an attempt to fix my mistake, but then I get a message that my device is corrupt. Still doesn't let me boot. Tried unlocking and relocking again. Same thing.

If I hold the power button down long enough, I can go back to the broken Android screen. The Start option has the same problem as above. Restart bootloader just shuts the phone off for a split second, then goes back to the broken android screen. Recovery mode doesn't work as described above. I'm afraid to go with "Power off", I'm afraid it might ruin my phone.

I can re-re-unlock the bootloader and go back to the "can't check for corruption" message. Re-re-locking it makes the "your device is corrupt" message again. What do I do? I'm afraid I might have already ruined the phone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that fastboot mode is working and bootloader is already unlocked, so what you can do in such a case is flash the stock firmware in the device. You can either [flash it via fastboot](https://developers.google.com/android/images) itself or via recovery. The one with recovery is a bit safer.

Full OTA image for Nexus and Pixel devices can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/android/ota) along with the instructions. If the instructions there do not work for you, here is what to do:

1. Download TWRP (a custom recovery) for [your device](https://twrp.me/Devices/) and follow the instructions there to flash it. You can alternatively directly boot into TWRP by using this command:

   ```
   fastboot boot recovery.img
   ```

   Make sure to rename the downloaded TWRP image to *recovery.img* and provide the full path to wherever you have downloaded it within the command.
2. Download the full OTA image in the PC.
3. In TWRP, go to Advanced → Sideload, and push the slider to begin sideloading. In the PC, issue this command:

   ```
   adb sideload FULL_OTA_IMAGE.zip
   ```

   Replace FULL_OTA_IMAGE.zip with the actual name and path of the full OTA image you have downloaded. Once it reaches 100%, your sideloading is finished. You can now issue the command `adb reboot` or reboot from the TWRP.

Your phone should boot fine now. Note that this would remove TWRP if you had installed it earlier. This does not locks the bootloader though.